Huge data uploads to Azure cloud through Exchange
A user in my Azure hybrid environment has his exchange uploading 200 gb ip addresses coming in as Microsoft data centers.  Im trying to run the command in powershell of
Get-MailTrafficReport -StartDate  -EndDate  -EventType Send | Where-Object {$_.User -eq ''}
to try and see what is going on with these uploads
I ran this but need more
mailbox stats
exchange data
I tried to run this command for details but got an error message,  I ran it from the azure powershell and also after connecting to exchangeonline but the same error after importing exchangeonlinemgt
Get-MailTrafficReport -StartDate  -EndDate  -EventType Send | Where-Object {$_.User -eq ''}
Get-MailTrafficReport : The term 'Get-MailTrafficReport' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script
file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct
and try again.
At line:1 char:1

Get-MailTrafficReport -StartDate 2024-07-18 -EndDate 2024-07-24

  + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-MailTrafficReport:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException




get-help -name get-mailtrafficreport
Get-Help: Get-Help could not find get-mailtrafficreport
cant get the get-mailtrafficreport to run in cloud powershell or on prem??
